# is it possible to insert an object into mongo whose property values are based on what's currently in the collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

let's say i have a collection of work items. JS code will add to the collection, some other process will pull off work items and work on them. for the task at hand, we're concerned only with insertion.

each inserted item has a `status`. let's say the allowed values on insert are `ready` and `waiting`. its value depends on whether there exists a "like" object already in the collection.

is there a way to atomically do the insert, such that the correct value of `status` will be set? currently, i'm making a quick read call first to determine `status`, but am running into concurrency issues w/ so many work items being created at once.

logically, i'm trying to do the following:

```
await WorkItems.create({
    matchingId,
    status: {
        $cond: [
            {
                $eq: ['$matchingId', matchingId],
                $eq: ['$status', {$in: ['ready', 'processing']}],
            },
            'waiting', 'ready'],
    },
});
```

... but i feel i'm way off syntactically, if this is even possible. i've also been looking at `$merge` into the same collection (i'm on mongo 4.4), but i'm not seeing my way to a solution.

so... is this possible? and if so, how should i approach it?